# Value semantics in range based for loop of pointer container

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, containers

So I want to write a container for pointers that sort of hides the fact that it is a pointer container. And for my `AddMember` function, this works, kind of.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T*>
{
public:
    void AddMember(T& newMember)
    {
        this->push_back(&newMember);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    MyVector<int> vec;
    vec.AddMember(a);
    vec.AddMember(b);

    for (auto& member : vec)
    {
        std::cout << "Address:" << member << " Value: " << *member << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, is it possible to implement presumably `begin()` and `end()` in a way that the range-based for loop gets value semantics? I.e. just `member` gives you the value? I don't want to use the boost ptr containers, because this is going to be a non-owning container.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  What problem are you really try to solve?

Comment: I want to wrap a std pointer container, give it some extra functions and value semantics. The part I'm struggling with I've shown. Not sure what else to tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, is it possible to implement presumably begin() and end() in a way that the range-based for loop gets value semantics?

Yes. Just like every other container, you will need to provide `begin` and `end` that return iterators.

You cannot use `std::vector<T*>::iterator` directly, because it has the wrong value type, but you can implement your iterator on top of it. This kind of wrapper iterator is called an iterator adaptor.

Lucky for you, boost already contains a library of iterator adaptors, so you don't need to implement from scratch. You may want to take a look at `boost::indirect_iterator` in particular.

---

PS. Avoid publicly inheriting standard containers. They don't have a virtual destructor, so it becomes easy to mistakenly write programs that have undefined behaviour.